# MSSQL, PDO, error when inserting XML string: General error: 102 Incorrect syntax near '<?xml version="1.0"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to insert XML string into a MSSQL database from PHP. I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 Incorrect syntax near ' (a chunk of the xml follows).

The prepared statement is:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('
   INSERT INTO [System_XmlExchangeImport] ([Create_ID], [ImportCode], [InputXml]) 
   VALUES (?, ?, ?);
');
$result = $stmt->execute(array('ABCDEFGHKAJSDKLJ', $code, $xml));
```

The `$xml` is a valid XML string. The same XML can be inserted OK using an identical statement in an SQL client app (sqlectron)

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Read about $PDO::quote() or something similar to allow you to remove special characters of the xml.  Try to  'echo' your final SQL query

Comment: Another option: use simplexml_load_string($yourXMLstring);

Comment: php.net on PDO::quote says: "you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote()" . It seems it makes no sense to try and use both. Also what do you mean by using simplexml_load_string? I need to insert the XML string. What should I do with the resulting object?

Comment: Is the "chunk of the xml" that follows approximately 4096 bytes? In php.ini you may need to set `mssql.textlimit = 2147483647` and `mssql.textsize = 2147483647`, ref: [The problem of truncating text from SQL Server in PHP](https://www.programcreek.com/2010/01/php-display-text-from-sql-server/) Also, if you're inserting into a column with the `xml` data type, SQL Server doesn't like being told what the encoding is (it expects UTF-16) so it might help to remove the `encoding="windows-1250"`.

Comment: @RadovanBezak Two questions: 1) What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server (`pdo_mssql`, `pdo_sqlsrv`, ...)? 2) What is the `System_XmlExchangeImport` table structure? And, if possible, post the actual `XML`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by encoding. The XML was encoded with Windows-1250, but the database connection was opened with UTF-8 charset:

```
$connString = "dblib:version=7.0;host=$dbIp:$dbPort;dbname=$dbName;charset=UTF-8;";
$this->db = new PDO($connString, $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

After changing `UTF-8` to `WINDOWS-1250` in the DSN (`$connString`):

```
$connString = "dblib:version=7.0;host=$dbIp:$dbPort;dbname=$dbName;charset=WINDOWS-1250;";
```

the XML can be inserted with no problem.